# I'm trying to learn Blender to animate. Am I doing it right?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, animation, shaders

The idea of making 3D animations to tell stories has always been attractive to me. Yesterday, I decided to stop hesitating and began learning to use Blender. I am using the YouTube channel tutor4u's tutorials on how to make an alarm clock and how to animate it. I hope to achieve a basic idea of modeling, so then I can make models to animate, which I also hope to learn. I also plan to learn shading and coloring to make it look nice. So far, it is going smoothly, but I feel like as soon as I finish the tutorials, I'll be stuck, and anything I want to make will still be too complex. Simply put: I feel like I'm going to run into a wall trying to learn Blender. Am I worrying too much? Am I learning Blender right? Where do I go after a few tutorials?

*Side Note: I'm not asking specifically for tutorials. I'm asking for the most efficient way to learn Blender. I think adding the name of the tutorial I am using would be relevant.*

Comment: This question isn't fit for a Q&A format. Go ask it on one of the Blender forums, but this site is only for specific questions which need specific answers. If you run into anything that can be answered in such a way, please feel free to come back and ask it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it right. It's kind of like learning to walk, starting with support from another person. The first time they let you go, you will fall. Get up again and continue trying.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I honestly thought I had to do something more to learn.